# Setting a page wide image on a page that pushes all text to be below it (no overlay)

Tags: spacing, graphics, layout

I am working on a D&D style book in Latex, using the DnD latex template, and everything works well with the exception of inserting D&D-style spreads of images. These tend to be either a full top half of a page, a full bottom half of a page, or ~half lefthand side of page or ~half righthand side. Text is in 2 columns.

After some previous trials, I'm able to actually get a page-filling (wide) image at the top of a desired page using

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\node[anchor=north west, inner sep=0pt] at (current page.north west) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth, height=.5\paperheight]{img.png}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But there are two problems with this method. First, it covers up the chapter title (using documentstyle book) at the top of the page, and second, all of the rest of the text beside the title is currently agnostic to the image's existence (appearing over the image).

What I want is to "push" all the text (including the chapter title, if possible), to start on, and exist only in, the bottom half of this page, while the top half is the image. I can get this started by using, e.g., `\vspace{}` commands, but this only pushes the first column down to the right starting point; the second column still covers the image. I've tried all sorts of vfills, minipages, etc., to try to "cover up" the top half of the page from the text's perspective, but nothing seems to work so far.

I'm not sure the tikzpicture is the best route for doing the image, but it's the only way I've found so far that places the image margin-to-margin exactly where I want. If anything, I'd need a second document element that just slams a "block" on the whole top half of the page and forces text to flow around it. And as mentioned above, this particular case calls for the top half to be blocked, but in other cases, I'll have images on the bottom and need that blocked (pushing text to the following page) instead.

If anyone has any advice on a better method, I'd appreciate it! I tried wrapfigure and a few other options. I imagine things might be more complicated for the chapter titles -- I'm sure the style sheet sets its margin from the top of the page, and I'd need to be able to change this on the fly for different chapters if the chapter title seems to interfere with an image.

Comment: The main problem is that `\chapter` will start a new page.

Answer (score 1):

This modifies the amount of space skipped by `\chapter`.  You can reset it back to 50pt for normal chapters.

I also tried a flowfram solution, but the chapter title looked too low on the page, and I figured if I was going to have to change `\@makechapterhead` anyway...  Also, flowfram likes to stay inside the text area, so TikZ is probably the easiest way to overlay the margins.  You could use `\AddToHook` and test the page counter.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}% MWE only

\newlength{\mychapterskip}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{\vspace*{\mychapterskip}}{}{Failed}
\makeatother
  
\begin{document}
\setlength{\mychapterskip}{300pt}%
\chapter{Title}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\node[anchor=north west, inner sep=0pt] at (current page.north west) 
  {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth, height=.5\paperheight]{example-image}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```